# Select in Laravel

Tags: mysql, select, laravel, eloquent, ksort

I have a stupid little question.

As I already know a select query in Laravel will always return an array of results,
I have this query:

```
 $id = DB::select(
       'select id from users where username = ?', array(Session::get('theuser')));
```

by inserting this id into my table

```
DB::table('characters')->insert(array(
    'id'            => $id,
    'char_name'     => $charname,
    'char_dynasty'  => $dynastyname,                    
    'picture'       => 'Male1.png'                  
));
```

I will get the error: ksort() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given.
How can I get rid of this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The code available now is not relevant. If the exception is thrown in a framework file then please tell us the version, file name and line number. If it's in your code then show us the code where you're calling `ksort`.

Comment: I don't see `ksort` in any of the code

Comment: C:\wamp\www\CaughtMiddle\tutorial\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder.php
  // Since every insert gets treated like a batch insert, we will make sure the
  // bindings are structured in a way that is convenient for building these
  // inserts statements by verifying the elements are actually an array.
  else
  {
   foreach ($values as $key => $value)
   {
    ksort($value); $values[$key] = $value;
   }
  }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least one of `$id`, `$charname` or `$dynastyname` is an array and should not be.
You are using it wrong.

Below is a POC proving this.
The output is "Warning: ksort() expects parameter 1 to be array, integer given on line 13"
It runs as expected when providing `'id' => 'a'`.

```
function insert(array $values)
{

        if ( ! is_array(reset($values)))
        {
            $values = array($values);
        }

        else
        {
            foreach ($values as $key => $value)
            {
                ksort($value); $values[$key] = $value;
            }
        }

        var_dump($values);
}

insert(array(
    'id'            => array('a'),
    'char_name'     => 2,
    'char_dynasty'  => 3,                    
    'picture'       => 'Male1.png'                  
));
```

Comment: Yes, it is true. The problem is at 'id' => $id. When commenting this line, the insert query works as expected. I think $id is an array according to the Laravel documentation...select() always returns an array. I don't know how should I insert into my id column this $id array.

Comment: You can use the query builder (http://laravel.com/docs/queries#selects) with `first` instead of the equivalent `get` to build your queries, not the "raw" DB API.

Comment: Or you could just `array_pop` the first value out of `$id` if you know there's only one result anyway.

Comment: I have managed to make this work. I have used the following select query: $id = DB::table('users')->where('username', Session::get('theuser'))->pluck('id');    I don;t know how I managed to skip it. Thank you for your kind directions :)